# Python tkinter moving object in def that as been created in another def

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating flappy bird style game. And my problem is that i cant move tubes that has been created on another def.
My code is

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
window = Tk()
c = Canvas(window, width=800, height=800, bg='steelblue')
tube11 = randint(600, 650)
tube12 = randint(400, 700)
def createtubes():
    tube1 = c.create_rectangle(800, 800, tube11, tube12, fill='green')
    tube2 = c.create_rectangle(800, 0, tube11, 200, fill='green')   
def automovement():
    if True:
        c.move(tube1, -3.5, 0)
        c.move(tube2, -3.5, 0)
    window.update_idletasks()
    window.after(10, automovement)
window.after(60, createtubes)
window.after(10, automovement)
c.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just have your createtubes function return the objects it creates. then pass them to the function that needs to move them. You're going to have an easier time programming in general if your functions largely operate on their inputs and return their outputs.

Comment: Alternatively you could create a class and store important variables as members that your class functions operate on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a class

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
window = Tk()
c = Canvas(window, width=800, height=800, bg='steelblue')
tube11 = randint(600, 650)
tube12 = randint(400, 700)
class Tubes:
    def __init__(self):
        self.createtubes()
    def createtubes(self):
        self.tube1 = c.create_rectangle(800, 800, tube11, tube12, fill='green')
        self.tube2 = c.create_rectangle(800, 0, tube11, 200, fill='green')   
    def automovement(self):
        if True:
            c.move(self.tube1, -3.5, 0)
            c.move(self.tube2, -3.5, 0)
        window.update_idletasks()
        window.after(10, self.automovement)
tube = Tubes()
window.after(10, tube.automovement)
c.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Now it does not print any error tubes just tubes does not move.

Comment: Which one did you use? If you used the class one you have to say `tubes = Tubes()` and `window.after(10, tubes.autoMovement)`

Comment: I used the class one and I still get error tube1 is not defi

Comment: I used the class one and i got an error 'tube1' is not defined.

Comment: Ok i don't know why but when i copied that code it worked. Before that i writed that thing from browser and it did not work. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use tags option on your rectangles.

```
tube1 = c.create_rectangle(800, 800, tube11, tube12, fill='green', tags='tube')
tube2 = c.create_rectangle(800, 0, tube11, 200, fill='green', tags='tube')
```

And in your function only one move :

```
c.move('tube', -3.5, 0)
```